# SSO integrate custom apps

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I have question  about SSO  whose integrating  with my custom app.  I using

https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml 
and I set everything as like in official tutorial, but I don't understand flow sso.
https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php

I click login SSO in my app.  SSO start flow and redirect to onelogin provider where I have to type self credentials.  So..

1. what random user will be login ? (he not will been have credentials)
2. how connect user after login via sso with my app?  I should search this user in my database?

Could somebody explain me flow SSO (saml) via Onelogin  ?

Comment: I think OneLogin has really detail document on the flow how to use SAML for SSO

Comment: read the documentation mate its very clear

Comment: I read... and still don't understand, how random user can login..

Answer (score 0):

1. what random user will be login ?
   No random user. OneLogin is asking for the credentials of a specific user (at the ID entity provider's end)
2. how connect user after login via sso with my app?
   If you app is configured correctly OneLogin will submit a POST request to you app. You app should evaluate the request (use the toolkit) and validate it (ex. resp.is_valid?) . The information about the user is provided in the request so you can either authorize the user if the nameid (ex email) exists in your app or provision (create) a user if that is what you want to do.

I hope this high level info helps you